# Starting with GIS For Developers?

Tags: geoserver, references

I'm a programmer, and I'll probably have to write code for some kind of a Geoserver based platform. (probably will have to maintain the server too).
My knowledge in geography is (shamefully) quite minimal and my background in GIS  is 0.

I seek a programmer-oriented list of things I better add to my to-do list, in order to turn from someone new to an expert in the least painful way possible.

What I've done so far:

- Skimmed through the Geoserver manual (including the REST API manual)
- Got a book called "GeoServer Beginner’s Guide" and read a little.